# Filtering and sorting a data feed with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Let's say I have a feed of apartment listings that I need to be able to filter by price, beds, location, etc and also need to sort by price and date.

Is this a good scenario for Knockout? Are there any similar projects/examples for this kind of scenario. If not, I guess I will just use Handlebars.js templates

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's an excellent use of Knockout, I'm assuming you will be retrieving data via Ajax/REST API, etc.

Though note that it's a UI+Data binding library - so it doesn't provide some "out-of-the-box" UI components for you to just "plug in" to do what you are describing.

Comment: Yes, I can format the data feed however I like (json\xml) and was planning to use querystrings to filter and sort the data. So...it sounds like it should be as easy as binding this model (json feed) to some custom template. Thanks!